# UDP connection i/o timeout while port is reachable

Tags: firewall, connection, udp, netcat

on one server we encountered an issue where all kinds of UDP connections are failing. The same application and tests work on other servers with the same OS and similar setup.

```
nc -vz -u 83.61.**.** 7092
Connection to 83.61.**.** 7092 port [udp/*] succeeded!
```

With the go app:

```
read udp 5.9.**.**:49696->83.61.**.**:7092: i/o timeout
```

We tested it with a php and golang app.

We have tried it with a fully disabled firewall as well.

What could be the cause if netcat succeeds but other applications can't.

Comment: UDP is a _connectionless_ protocol, so there are no UDP connections.

Comment: The UDP test from openbsd-netcat is pretty worthless. It doesn't actually tell you anything useful, like whether the other end received the UDP traffic. In particular it will report succeeded! if the UDP packets were dropped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Connection to [...] port [udp/*] succeeded!
```

is a missleading message from netcat. netcat can't know if the port is open with UDP because this is not a connected protocol unlike TCP.

use the good old way:
look at the other side if your UDP packets comes in with tcpdump